# How can i open this filescript?

Tags: python, file

[image]

I can't open 'high_scores.py' file which is in 'practice-files' directory

Maybe i write incorrect query for opening?

Comment: That first attempt says that you are in a "practice_files" directory trying to run "high_scores.py" in that same directory. Since it doesn't work, clearly the file isn't there. I noticed a name issue ... the directory is not "practice-files" (note the dash). You could do `ls high_scores.py`, but its not going to be there.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark - that's not going to work since the python command line version didn't work.

Comment: P;;ease post the information as text, not an image. Its annoying not being able to copy/paste your paths.

Comment: You could go back a few directories, like maybe to the lab8 directory. Then do `find -iname high_scores.py` to see where it is.

Comment: directory name - practice_files  ,   file name which is there - high_scores.py   I have just copied and inserted here

Comment: You need to do an `ls`.  The evidence from your post is that the file `high_scores.py` is not in there.  Note that spelling is important.

Comment: i accidently wrote practice-files instead of practice_files in post